# Bitmex API (PHP), cancel one order doesn't work

Tags: php, api, bitmex

I'm using PHP. When I try to cancel one active order via API i got error:

```
"error" => array:2 [▼
   "message" => "orderIDs or clOrdIDs must be sent."
   "name" => "ValidationError"
]
```

I put orderID as array (this is my lib method):

```
public function cancelOrder($orderID) {
   $symbol = self::SYMBOL;
   $data['method'] = "DELETE";
   $data['function'] = "order";
   $data['params'] = array(
      "orderID" => $orderID, // ['r5ff364da-4243-8ee3-7853-6fb0f9f7e44d']
   );
   return $this->authQuery($data);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
https://www.bitmex.com/api/explorer/#!/Order/Order_cancel

Similar Problem: [bitmex api php, cancel 1 order not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013678/bitmex-api-php-cancel-1-order-not-working)

Comment: I mean I've never used the API, but it says *orderIDs or clOrdIDs must be sent*, and you aren't sending either of them - your code just sends orderID in singular.

Comment: orderIDs -->OR<-- clOrdIDs must be sent

Comment: Right, and you're sending `orderID`, which isn't either of them

Comment: Hm.. API docs says: Either an orderID or a clOrdID must be provided. I can send 1 id or array of id's. I sent 1 id, so what is problem?) I can't understand

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but thought i would answer as I finally figured this out, and imagine it would be useful for anyone else trying to use Bitmex API with PHP (Especially if you're using bitmex-api-php wrapper on kstka's github).

First, put the order Id number into an array, even if it's just one:

```
public function cancelOrder($orderId) {
    $orderArr = array($orderId);
    $symbol = self::SYMBOL;
    $data['method'] = "DELETE";
    $data['function'] = "order";
    $data['params'] = array(
      'orderID' => $orderArr,
    );
    return $this->authQuery($data);
}
```

Then you need to make sure your params are json encoded, but only for DELETE

```
if($method == "GET" || $method == "POST" || $method == "PUT") {
    $params = http_build_query($data['params']);
} elseif($method == "DELETE") {
    $params = json_encode($data['params']);
}
```

and then, most importantly, you need to ensure the CURL headers are json encoded:

```
if($data['method'] == "DELETE") {
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $headers[] = 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: DELETE';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
 }
```

You should be away laughing. This took my forever to figure out!

Comment: That was it!  I was missing json in the header for a delete. Thank you for sharing.